# How to get session JWT token for further API calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am working with aws API gateway and my requirement includes setting authorizers on each end-point. Tester will test my API with POSTMAN collections and he needs to provide the JWT authentication token. How can I provide him the token so that all of the APIs can be tested.

Project includes web app, where "amazon-cognito-identity-js" package is used to get JWT token and call APIs. But tester need to test only APIs. One of the way which I think is to create an end-point where username and password will be sent, it will then call the lambda function which will use same package to authenticate and return the JWT token for further API calls. But I am not sure whether this is best practice.

I tried few aws documentation like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Lambda Authorizer`, where you authenticate against a Cognito JWT Token would meet your requirements. For more details about validating Cognito JWT Tokens, kindly refer to this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html). You could have the same Authorizer configured for every Resource of your REST API in AWS API Gateway.

Comment: my concern was to generate the jwt token itself and **not to verify it**. As I have mentioned, I have my cognito authoriser set for each of the api.

Comment: Please look into InitiateAuth and AdminInitiateAuth API calls.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. I also came across one aws document, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html